# Why MongoDB returns unfiltered results?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I'm doing a filtered query on MongoDB table but the results doesn't match with filter criterias.

I'm using the following query:

```
db.url_repository.find({"p":0,"pr":0}).limit(10)
```

But my results are

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568742bb60d99e329a115b7a"), "pr" : 0, "p" : 1, "u" : "http://www.blabla", "type" : "regular", "ct" : ISODate("2016-01-02T05:23:39.586Z"), "dt" : ISODate("2016-08-20T14:59:48.759Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568742bb60d99e329a115b7b"), "pr" : 0, "p" : 1, "u" : "http://www.blabla", "type" : "regular", "ct" : ISODate("2016-01-02T05:23:39.586Z"), "dt" : ISODate("2016-08-20T15:00:00.392Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568742bb60d99e329a115b7c"), "pr" : 0, "p" : 1, "u" : "http://www.blabla", "type" : "regular", "ct" : ISODate("2016-01-02T05:23:39.586Z"), "dt" : ISODate("2016-08-20T15:00:12.537Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568742bb60d99e329a115b7d"), "pr" : 0, "p" : 1, "u" : "http://www.blabla/", "type" : "regular", "ct" : ISODate("2016-01-02T05:23:39.587Z"), "dt" : ISODate("2016-08-20T15:00:15.887Z") }
```

As you can see, it doesn't obey to rules and results are including documents with "p":1

These results are returning on MongoDB shell but also pymongo (Python library) returns right results. I couldn't find what can be the reason for this.

Thank you very much for your support.

Edit: explain() results are also below

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "crawlerdb.url_repository",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "p" : {
                                                "$eq" : 0
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "pr" : {
                                                "$eq" : 0
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "limitAmount" : 10,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "pr" : {
                                                "$eq" : 0
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "p" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "is_processed",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "p" : [
                                                        "[0.0, 0.0]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                                "limitAmount" : 10,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "p" : 1,
                                                        "pr" : -1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "url_is_processed_priority",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "p" : [
                                                                "[0.0, 0.0]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "pr" : [
                                                                "[0.0, 0.0]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "barcelona",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.7",
                "gitVersion" : "4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: "These results are returning on MongoDB shell but also pymongo (Python library) returns right results" - to be honest I don't get that sentence. Do you get the correct results with pymongo but not with the mongo shell?

Comment: that's right @DAXaholic.

Comment: Ok - but that's weird. I just tested it with your shown results and your query and there are no matches. Could you show us the mongo shell output of your query when appending `.explain()` to the end?

Comment: @DAXaholic I've added explain() results to my question, it looks like I've also wrongly defined index?

Comment: I've updated the MongoDB to new minor version, now it's also gathers deleted data! Looks like it's caching but couldn't solve the reason yet.